# Implied subject with "i.e."

Tags: grammaticality, clauses, subjects

Is it required that an `i.e.` clause have an explicit subject? Preferred?

*E.g.*, is the following sentence correct?

> She was not amenable, i.e., turned him down.

Or would it have to be

> She was not amenable, i.e., she turned him down.

*I.e.*, can you use `i.e.` to clarify only part of a sentence, or must you use the full sentence (and restate the the other part that didn't bear clarifying)?

Comment: My rule: If the sentence reads fine when you substitute "that is" for "i.e." then you can go with it.  (Personally I don't think the first sentence reads as nicely as the second.)

Comment: @Hellion I use that rule too! So the first sentence is not grammatically incorrect, just awkward?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Merriam Webster dictionary, ".... i.e is an abbreviation for the Latin expression for id est, which means “that is” in Latin. It introduces a rewording or a clarification of a statement that has just been made or of a word that has just been used."

There is no reason to use i.e. unless you follow it with a clause specifying or explaining.

For a clause introducing a not "explicit subject", perhaps you are thinking of *inter alia*, a Latin phrase that means among other things, or including.

Comment: There is no basis for using *inter alia* in either case. I have edited the original question, if it was for some reason confusing.